# How to emit floating point immediate operand using decimal representation in gnu assembler

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, floating-point, gnu-assembler

For example, 0.5f is 0x3F000000 in the target platform. I want to use something like `movl $0.5,%eax` instead of `movl $0x3F000000,%eax`

The assembler is from TDM-GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a separate constant with either [`.float`, `.single` or `.double` directives](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.26/as/Pseudo-Ops.html)

For example

```
.data
        half: .float 0.50
.text
.globl _start
        _start:
        movl half, %eax
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/AVX,_AVX2,_FMA3,_FMA4

You can also use E/F/G/H constraints in [inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Simple-Constraints.html)

```
static const float half = 0.5f;
__asm__ __volatile__ ("\n\
   movl %1, %eax        %1"
   : "g" (half)
   ) ;
```

Comment: Does the former actually insert an *immediate*, or does it load a value from the `.data` section?

Comment: it loads a value from memory. I haven't found a way to insert an immediate yet